# There are symbols like Â and so on in database, what to do?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few symbols in my description like Â â € and so on. Can I do anything about it? Or if it's in database, I can't do nothing now?

Comment: Those are perfectly fine symbols. The `Ââ` is used in the French language; the `€` is the symbol of our common currency here in Europe. What's the problem? (I think I know what your problem is, but *please* explain it better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sort of depends what the problem actually is...

If it's that those characters are **supposed** to be there (such as "Mañana" in Spanish) then you'll need to ensure everything is in UTF-8... the best way is to:

1: check the database tables are in "utf-8" encoding (if not convert them to utf-8)

2: as Martin noted, ensure the database connector is utf-8 using something like:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8'); //note that MySQL uses no hyphen here
```

3: ensure the the document is utf-8 (you can add a header at the top)

```
<?php header('Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

4: just to be on the safe side, add it in as a meta tag as well

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

---

**HOWEVER**

It's quite possible you've got some duff characters in the database where something like ISO-8859-1 has been juggled to UTF-8, badly. In this case you'll notice things like **Â£** where what you actually want is **£** (because UTF-8 characters contain more data than ISO-8859-1 characters, that extra data can become an additional character if you're not careful).

In which case your best bet is to clean the database (you could probably do something like `UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, 'Â£', '£')` for common "errors") and then convert the whole kaboodle to UTF-8 (as outlined above) to avoid the problem recurring.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having such characters,

1. Set the charset for your form. HTML forms have charset attribute and value. You can use UTF-8
2. Set Charset for the Document, via PHP or using META tags ( but this only works on the output )
3. set Charset for the db table
4. get a class/function to do ascii character conversion as part of your data filtering and escaping