# Special characters displaying incorrectly with html entities

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I'm having trouble with some data I've imported from an XML file. Unfortunately I'm working with some spanish characters, usually I'd just htmlentites them, but it's not working.

Examples of what I'm trying to display:

```
PRCE PEDUCED FROM 1,395,000Ã¢Â‚Â¬

A delightful south facing villa located in GÃƒÂ©nova
```

Should be:

```
PRCE PEDUCED FROM 1,395,000€

A delightful south facing villa located in GÃƒÂ©nova  (no idea what that should be...)
```

Any ideas?

*Edit:* **Table encoding is utf8_spanish_ci, PHP is currently set to ISO-8859-1 as a ditch effort. Client side is currently UTF-8**

```
$text = nl2br($Property->description); 
$trans_text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $text);
echo $trans_text;
echo htmlentities($trans_text, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
```

Comment: It's mapping one desired char, €, onto six bytes? That sounds like it's going through a conversion twice, maybe € -(utf8)> e2 82 ac -(??) -> c3 a2 c3 2c c3 ac.

Comment: Ulrich, I wish I understood that. I think you're saying it's been converted twice, and now it's six bytes; unfortunately this is how it's stored in the database. I'm trying to figure out how to display it on an HTML page. Any thoughts?

Comment: The best fix is to rectify your import rather than fixing your output

Comment: Hmm. So there's no the solution to this after the fact? I would strongly prefer not to fix the import, due to deadlines and the length of time the import takes...

Comment: it probably means that you've filtered the text using htmlentities() both when you saved the text and then again when you retrieve it. If you run € through htmlentities you'll get the "code" for that symbol, and when you run that code through htmlentities it will display something like your example output

Comment: Hmm, my import uses utf8_encode, and the only other operation applied is mysql_real_escape_strings on the save function. So, just to clarify, I better get coding this fixed import now as there is absolutely no reversal solution / godly MySQL operation? I'd love to be able to accept a solution on this one! ;)

Comment: Errm, I'm thinking some bad ass usage of iconv?

Comment: I think I found your problem.. the ISO-8859-1 charset doesn't contain the euro (€) sign

Comment: Whenever I try to use that it doesn't work. If I remove the second two arguments it displays? :/ Really confused now. My current ditch effort is in the edit on the original post.

Comment: @Tom to be honest, I don't mind getting rid of the characters, so n with tilde becomes just an "n," but I can't seem to get to this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the table on http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html I concluded in two steps:
Ã¢Â‚Â¬ => â‚¬ => €
GÃƒÂ©nova => GÃ©nova => Génova

I believe you can update the content of your database like this:
`UPDATE tablename SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, 'Ã¢Â‚Â¬', '€');`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, please could you let me know how you did this? I'll need to convert probably about another 10 characters. :)

Comment: Check the table: GÃƒÂ©nova gives Ãƒ => Ã and Â© => © combining them to Ã© => é

Comment: @CharlesKirk this works great for texts already screwed up because of character encoding problems, but if it's your current code that causes it, your characters will keep going back to  Ã¢Â‚Â¬  etc.

Comment: Yeah, make sure that the encoding is set correctly where the content is inserted in the database and also when updateing the current database better use the htmlentities so don't update Ã¢Â‚Â¬ to € but to &euro;

Answer (score 0):

Check your database connection character set... it's possible you're running into this issue:

[There are symbols like Â and so on in database, what to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473965/there-are-symbols-like-and-so-on-in-database-what-to-do/8474356#8474356)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've implemented all of this, and it doesn't seem to be the issue. I posted what is literally stored in the database, I am now using utf8_unicode in the database, and utf-8 everywhere else.