# Arabic character "???????" on php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

here is my problem, i have an arabic database mysqli UTF8_general_ci and the charset of my php file is UTF-8
when i seled data i get "?????????????".
on php my admin i can write and read with no problem, also on php i can, but the problem is when is when i get data from the database! here is my code:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>

$connexion = new mysqli(HOST_DB,USER_DB,MDP_DB,DB_NAME);
        if ($connexion->error) {
            die('Une erreur s\'est produite :' .$connexion->error);
        }
        else{
            $sql = "SELECT nom, description, date, formateur, image, prix, lieux FROM news";
            if ($result = mysqli_query($connexion,$sql)) {
                while ($ligne = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo'
                        <ul>
                            <li><figure>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h1>'.$ligne["nom"].'</h1>
                                    <p>'.$ligne["description"].'</p>
                                    <strong>اليوم:'.$ligne["date"].'</strong><br/>
                                    <strong>المكان:'.$ligne["lieux"].'</strong><br/>
                                    <strong>المدرس:'.$ligne["formateur"].'</strong><br/>
                                    <strong>الثمن: '.$ligne["prix"].'دينار</strong>
                                    </figcaption>
                                <img src="Images/'.$ligne["image"].'" height="250px" width="250px">
                            </figure></li>
                        </ul>
                    ';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This looks like an error that you could see when the charset is not set for the mysql connection. Try to set it for the connection.

Comment: Just add this code just before your select query: mysql_query("set characer set utf8");

Comment: Did you create your database using UTF-8 encoding too? `CREATE DATABASE db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8`

Comment: yes when i created the batabase the encoding is utf8_general_ci, and i added mysql_query("set characer set utf8"); but still the problem :(

Comment: Probably your browser is acting up, did you try to change character encoding to UTF-8 in the browser ?

Comment: This seems to be a recurring theme, see if my answer to this question covers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473965/there-are-symbols-like-and-so-on-in-database-what-to-do/8474356#8474356

Comment: i use chrome, i changed firefox, IE, and Opera, the same problem, i used xampp and i changed wamp server, and the same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from XAMPP, i swiched to Wamp server and rebooted the machine and all work fine,
Thanks ALL

Answer (score 5):

put this code after the connection to mysql. 
    mysqli_set_charset($connexion,'utf8');
this is final code for connection to database:
    $connexion = new mysqli(HOST_DB,USER_DB,MDP_DB,DB_NAME);
    mysqli_set_charset($connexion,'utf8');

Answer (score 1):

it will work you have to change my.ini file inside mysql\bin and add the below line

character-set-server = utf8

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

will modify the header to your encoding

Answer (score 0):

Run this SQL query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf-8'
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf-8'

Answer (score -2):

Please check your PHP version using PHP Version Manager. You should upgrade PHP to 7.1.33 or later to solve this problem, otherwise the above solutions do not help much.