# MySQLi: Non-English Characters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a Table named "status" Which is used to store objects status. The table has 5 columns and except "symbol" column which it's type is VARCHAR utf8mb4_unicode_ci, All the others are just typical integers.

The problem is that because the symbol column can store English and Non-English characters, It returns NULL(With `var_dump($row)`) When I use my php file "getStatus.php" to retrieve the data from a row with Non-English symbol but It works well when I use English characters as symbol.

This is my table(the symbol on the second row is "تست"):

[image: my table]

This is the php code, "getStatus.php" :

```
if(!isset($_GET["symbol"]))
        die("please specify the symbol");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","******","****");
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM `status` WHERE `symbol` =  '" . $_GET["symbol"] . "';";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if (!$result)
        die("unable to retreive status");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row["status"] == 1)
        echo $row["percentage"];
else
        echo -1;
```

I can successfully get data When I execute `getStatus.php?symbol=EU` which calls mysql with

```
SELECT * FROM `status` WHERE `symbol` = 'ER';
```

But When I execute `getStatus.php?symbol=تست`, I got null! The confusing point is that if I copy the query and enter it in mysql command line It will work but it doesn't work when I send the same query with mysqli in php!!

```
SELECT * FROM `status` WHERE `symbol` = 'تست';
```

Why it works in mysql commandline and phpmyadmin but not with mysqli?

Comment: Use 4 space indentation for code blocks rather than `>` blockquote formatting. That will preserve all your code and apply syntax highlighting correctly.

Comment: add this after you connect (mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8'); ) --- source http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,209072,209072

Comment: You probably need to `urlencode()` that value before requesting it in the query string.  If you are submitting this from a form, that should be automatic, but if you are testing it manually, you would need to do it as `getStatus.php?symbol=%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA` PHP will then automatically decode it.

Comment: You have a serious SQL injection problem though, using `$_GET['symbol']` directly in the query. Review the mysqli `prepare()/bind_param()/execute()` examples on [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), but at a minimum, you _must_ call `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['symbol'])` to sanitize that value.

Comment: you are using msqli so check here --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829816/php-set-character-names-using-mysqli

Comment: @Tasos Non of them worked.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I used the manual form getStatus.php?symbol=%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA  But it didn't worked

Comment: Then you may have client encoding problems as another commenter suggested.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I did what Tasos suggested but it didn't work, Why it works with mysql cmd if it has encoding problems

Comment: its probably the web server brand you have like here that has the problem cause those solutions should work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604657/arabic-character-on-php-and-mysql

Comment: Dont use the curency name as get value, switch to using mysql table ids. So that getStatus.php?symbol=تست becomes getStatus.php?symbol=14. Adjust your sql code accordingly

Comment: @Tasos This one worked!!!