# Issue using html_entity_decode()

Tags: php, function, character-encoding, html-entities

Well I am building this crawler where i crawl article content that is not in english. However once i store the content to the database the html_entity_decode doesn't do the job correct, thus I am getting weird characters not the wanted ones.

This is my line of code that I am using for that part:

```
    $content=html_entity_decode($content, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

However, as mentioned above, instead of getting this character

> **ë**

I am getting this one

> **Ã«**

Can you please advise on this issue?

Comment: You decode the character that already is in your database? Or before you put it there? When do you do encode it?

Comment: ISO-8859-1 <- -> UTF-8 issue; you've got to ensure you're working in the same character set throughout the whole stack from the front end to the db connector to the db tables. Possible duplicate of  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473965/there-are-symbols-like-Â-and-so-on-in-database-what-to-do/8474356#8474356

Comment: @Chilion I was trying to decode it before storing into a database, that way all my data is correct. Thanks

Comment: @CD001 I will check that and let you know! Thank you!

Comment: @CD001 I just went through your steps on the other post, and it worked. I had all the tables on the database set to utf8 however, I haven't done the mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); and the meta tags, with the header.


Thanks man!

Comment: No worries : `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");` that's the bit I used to miss as well ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically went through the steps on the link below, and it worked like a charm.

[There are symbols like Â and so on in database, what to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473965/there-are-symbols-like-%C3%82-and-so-on-in-database-what-to-do/8474356#8474356)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$content = html_entity_decode($content, ENT_QUOTES);
```